# Django Rest Framework nested relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new in using Django, I need your help

So, I created a model like this

> **models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Pegawai(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Barang(models.Model):
    pegawai = models.ForeignKey(Pegawai,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='barangs',)
    nama_barang = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    harga_barang = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.pegawai.name
```

my serializer:

> **serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers, fields

from .models import Pegawai,Barang


class BarangSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Barang
        fields = (
                'pegawai', 
                'nama_barang',
                'harga_barang',
                )

class PegawaiSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    barangs = BarangSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Pegawai
        fields = (
                'id',
                'name', 
                'alias',
                'barangs',
                )
```

my views:

> **views.py**

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .serializers import PegawaiSerializer,BarangSerializer
from .models import Pegawai,Barang

class BarangViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Barang.objects.all().order_by('nama_barang')
    serializer_class = BarangSerializer

class PegawaiViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Pegawai.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = PegawaiSerializer
```

**Results:**

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Ryan",
    "alias": "R",
    "barangs": [
        {
            "pegawai": 5,
            "nama_barang": "burjo",
            "harga_barang": "1234"
        },
```

**Question:** how can i change pegawai fields from id to name? like this:

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Ryan",
    "alias": "R",
    "barangs": [
        {
            "pegawai": Ryan,
            "nama_barang": "burjo",
            "harga_barang": "1234"
        },
```

I've searched some solutions but nothing works, I don't know where the problem is, so I need your guide. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method-1

Since you are defined **`__str__()`** method in your **`Pegawai`** model, you can use [**`StringRelatedField(...)`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)

```
class BarangSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pegawai = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = Barang
        fields = (
            'pegawai',
            'nama_barang',
            'harga_barang',
        )
```

## Method-2

use [**`CharField`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#charfield)

```
class BarangSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pegawai = serializers.CharField(source='pegawai.name')

    class Meta:
        model = Barang
        fields = (
            'pegawai',
            'nama_barang',
            'harga_barang',
        )
```

---

#### UPDATE-1

To solve issues while creation of model objects, override the **`to_representation()`** method

```
class BarangSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Barang
        fields = (
            'pegawai',
            'nama_barang',
            'harga_barang',
        )

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['pegawai'] = instance.pegawai.name
        return rep
```

Comment: This one is works..

but when i tried to input into Barang, i got errors like this:
AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable dotted-source fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `myapi.serializers.BarangSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on dotted-source serializer fields.

Solution?

Comment: but how if I want to get all the Pegawai into the BarangSerializer?

Comment: Since your issue mentioned in the original post has been resolved, you should [**ask a new question.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59657005/django-rest-framework-relationship .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

> use serializers.CharField.

```
class BarangSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pegawali=serializers.CharField(source="pegawali.name")
    class Meta:
        model = Barang
        fields = (
            'pegawai', 
            'nama_barang',
            'harga_barang',
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the fields value in serializer with DRF RelatedField:

```
class BarangSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    pegawai = serializers.RelatedField(source='pegawai.name', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Barang
        fields = (
                'pegawai', 
                'nama_barang',
                'harga_barang',
                )
```